# How to check if file has been copied to output directory because it was newer than one previously?

Tags: c#

I have setup process which persist data onto my database, the data consist of small json which using a json deserializer become an object, and that object is then persisted to the database. My problem here is that it takes time to persist all data in to the database during runtime, and most often I only need to do it case of file has been changed, or something has been added to it.

I know this is the case when a new file is being copied to the output directory, as the file setting for the json files are to copy if the file is newer.

But how do i utilize this in my application,  currently I just purge my database, and reinsert everything but since most of the data is stale (meaning it hasn't changed for months) I wont need to reinsert them, but only those which has changed.

So how do check which files has been changed/overwritten in the output directory from my application?

Project setting states, that my files are copied to the output directory if they are newer, but how can I from my application detect whether a file is newer or not?

I have to use the output directory to check whether the file has been changed.

Comment: You can use datetime.

Comment: @CetinBasoz not sure on how i should use datetime => there would second of difference from when it copied to output directory to my application detects it

Comment: You can have UTC datetime data for all rows and that would do it. Since your question is not clear, nor do you have any sample it is almost impossible to understand your question really.

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question. It is very hard to understand what you want to achieve..

Comment: @Mono I have added some more information hopes it cover yours question

Comment: Compute a hash of each file and store it in your database, when it changes, you need to refresh your database copy from the file.

Comment: Is there no way check whether an file has been overwritten?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I would as much as possible try to solve this issue on the application layer, since it is the one inserting data into it. 

somehow this approach can be done on a application layer?

Comment: Is it just for your development?

Comment: yes @Mono but should also incorporate a solution public enviroments

Comment: In order to check if a file is new, or has been overwritten, you need to have *some* prior knowledge about the file, such as the last write time prior to it being overwritten by the compilation process. This prior knowledge has to be stored somewhere. If you check the last write time on the file, and compare that to some datetime in the database, you could figure out if the file is newer than the data, but then you need a datetime in the database to compare against. You can't compare against nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use override time of output directory file as only info to detect if you should sync changes.
Output content is created on build and publish actions so if file is overwritten it is done at those points not when you run application. You can build and publish your application multiple times without running it and question is: When is file overwritten?

After that you can run and stop your application multiple times and question is  : Is your file overwritten and synced with DB?

You can:
(1) use hashes or
(2) implement mechanism for versioning your files (File.GetLastWriteTime (path) and log that to DB after syncing data) or
(3) implement a mechanism to explicitly say you want to sync those files (some config flag that will be resetted after sync or copy of edited file which will be deleted after sync)